# how to copy from svn branch to another branch

Tags: svn, copy, branch

I am using SVN for version control. I have two branches V2 and V3. Please find the structure below

```
branches
    -v2
        -prj1
        -prj2
        -prj3
        -prj4
    -v3
        -prj1
        -prj2
        -prj3
```

See I dont have prj4 in branch V3. How can I copy the prj4 from branch v2 to the branch v3. I have tortoise svn installed in my machine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tortoise SVN UI > Copy to > Select the folder to copy. This worked for me.